# Getting reference to userdata in a table using luaL_ref?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-userdata

First of all, I appologize for not uploading the full code.

I'm trying to convert `userdata` to a `pointer` so it can be passed to other lua chunk using `lua_rawgeti()`.

If you see `outletRet()` function, it checks the type of a returned value, and if it's a `userdata`, it passes the pointer to other lua chunk by calling `outlet_pointer()` and it seems to work fine.

And if `userdata` is inside a `table`, `outletTable()` function is called. And if one of its elements is a `userdata` it also converts `userdata` to a `pointer` and then pass it to other chunk by calling `outlet_pointer()`.

However, when `luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX)` is called, it seems like it gets a reference to the whole `table` and not just `userdata` inside it.

How can I get the reference to the `userdata` and not the whole `table`?

```
void ofLua::outletTable() //called from outletRet() below
{
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    lua_pushnil(L);
    int ac = 0;
    t_atom *av = static_cast<t_atom *>(getbytes(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    while (lua_next(L, -2))
    {
        av = static_cast<t_atom *>(resizebytes(av, sizeof(t_atom) * ac,
                                               sizeof(t_atom) * (ac + 1)));
        if (lua_isboolean(L, -1))
        {
            av[ac].a_type = A_FLOAT;
            av[ac].a_w.w_float = static_cast<t_float>(lua_toboolean(L, -1));
        }
        else if (lua_isnumber(L, -1))
        {
            av[ac].a_type = A_FLOAT;
            av[ac].a_w.w_float = static_cast<t_float>(lua_tonumber(L, -1));
        }
        else if (lua_isstring(L, -1))
        {
            av[ac].a_type = A_SYMBOL;
            av[ac].a_w.w_symbol = gensym(lua_tostring(L, -1));
        }
        else if (lua_isuserdata(L, -1))
        {
            av[ac].a_type = A_POINTER;
        }
        ac++;
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    const ofeliaIO &io = dataPtr->io;
    if (io.hasMultiControlOutlets)
    {
        int last = (io.numOutlets >= ac ? ac : io.numOutlets) - 1;
        for (int i = last; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (av[i].a_type == A_FLOAT)
                outlet_float(io.outlets[i], av[i].a_w.w_float);
            else if (av[i].a_type == A_SYMBOL)
                outlet_symbol(io.outlets[i], av[i].a_w.w_symbol);
            else if (av[i].a_type == A_POINTER)
            {
                userDataRefVec.push_back(luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX));
                outlet_pointer(io.outlets[i], reinterpret_cast<t_gpointer *>(&userDataRefVec.back()));
                luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, userDataRefVec.back());
                userDataRefVec.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
    else
        outlet_list(dataPtr->ob.ob_outlet, &s_list, ac, av);
    freebytes(av, sizeof(t_atom) * ac);
}

void ofLua::outletRet()
{
    const ofeliaIO &io = dataPtr->io;
    if (!io.hasControlOutlet) return;
    if (lua_isnil(L, -1))
        outlet_bang(io.outlets[0]);
    else if (lua_isboolean(L, -1))
        outlet_float(io.outlets[0], static_cast<t_float>(lua_toboolean(L, -1)));
    else if (lua_isnumber(L, -1))
        outlet_float(io.outlets[0], static_cast<t_float>(lua_tonumber(L, -1)));
    else if (lua_isstring(L, -1))
        outlet_symbol(io.outlets[0], gensym(lua_tostring(L, -1)));
    else if (lua_isuserdata(L, -1))
    {
        userDataRefVec.push_back(luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX));
        outlet_pointer(io.outlets[0], reinterpret_cast<t_gpointer *>(&userDataRefVec.back()));
        luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, userDataRefVec.back());
        userDataRefVec.pop_back();
    }
    else if (lua_istable(L, -1))
        outletTable();
}
```

Comment: `outlet_pointer(io.outlets[0], reinterpret_cast<t_gpointer *>(&userDataRefVec.back()));`What is this?

Comment: @IllidanS4 That passes the address of `userDataRefVec`'s last element integer to other Lua chunk so the userData can be used there via `lua_rawgeti()`. I'm sorry I cannot explain more details.

Comment: Any reason to pass it as a pointer? Why not simply pass the integer?

Comment: @IllidanS4 It's because I wanted to distinguish between `number` and `userdata` so they don't clash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to convert userdata to a pointer

Don't. It's not the same, the pointer does not represent the userdata.
You can't retrieve Lua userdata object via pointer to its data area.

If you need to manipulate with userdata on native side, save the userdata in registry with `luaL_ref()`, and use returned integer as a reference. Later you can retrieve that object from registry and get pointer to its data area whenever you need. But don't store just the pointer.

As for the issue with referencing table, the object to be saved in registry with `luaL_ref()` must be on Lua stack top. But right now the only thing that stays on Lua stack top is the table. You copy that table's value to iterate with `while(lua_next())`, and anything that's read from the table within that loop is popped from the stack at the end of the loop.

Probably you shouldn't even build the `av` structure at all, and process the data immediately as you scan the original table. You don't need to ref/unref userdata then.
If you really must have that `av`, then instead of the pointer to userdata's memory save the integer index returned by `luaL_ref()`. And you should do it in the first loop, not in the second. The second loop then would do `lua_rawgeti()` to get userdata object, and after processing you can unref it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I call `luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);` in the first loop that is `while (lua_next(L, -2))`, my app crashes.

Comment: Moving `lua_pop(L,1);` inside while loop into each conditions except for `else if (lua_isuserdata(L,-1))` made it not crash. Maybe I should not call `lua_pop(L,1)` after calling `LuaL_ref()`?

Comment: @ZackLee, saving something with `luaL_ref()` will pop it off the stack, so make a copy with `lua_pushvalue()`.  But check this first - if the table you scan will live for entire time of processing, you don't need to save userdata in the registry. You can take the pointer to userdata memory area for `av`, and rely on the fact that the userdata will be kept alive by the table where it's stored. No need to ref/unref it then.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will give you a bounty tomorrow.